# Relation between 'As a matter of fact' and 'Matter-of-fact'

Tags: etymology, expressions

What is the relation between the expressions 'As a matter of fact' and 'Matter-of-fact'?

I'm aware of the meanings of these expressions; I'm just wondering if there is any relation between the two. I've looked into many dictionaries but haven't understood much about their similarities if there even are any.

Questions:

1. Do these expressions share a history of common origin?
2. Whether the latter is derived from the former considering their origin according to [this site](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/matter-of-fact)?
3. If these are completely independent expressions, then how come they are named almost the same? Is the hyphenated form going to twist the whole meaning?

I don't suppose we can use 'as a matter of fact' in place of 'matter-of-fact', right?

Comment: The difference seems to be usage: "matter of fact" is a noun phrase, and "matter-of-fact" is the adjectival use of that noun phrase to modify another noun or noun phrase. As might be expected, the noun phrase is found earlier (by more than a century, 1583) than the adjective derived from it (1712).

Comment: Use them as follows: If I argue with you and say "You have your facts wrong," I can start off my sentence with "_As a matter of fact_." If I speak to you casually, although the subject is serious, you could say my _matter-of fact_ manner was hiding my true intent.